# How to mention '@'mention integration with react webgifted chat

Tags: reactjs

Im using react-web-giftedchat  for my project.Still there is no proper documentation for that..can someone here help me to add mentions for the users.Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, do you have some code to show us so we can see what you have tried and help you ?

Comment: I dont have code and all...Just like whatsapp mentioning of @ it will show users..In gifted web chat how to implement that?